# Finding the probability that one of the given independent events happens

Tags: probability

> We have the events $D$, $F$ and $G$. Their probabilities are $P(D)=1/5$, $P(F)=1/6$ and $P(G) = 1/8$. Find the probability that one of these events happens. (It does not specify which.)

Thank you dear fellows. Wouldnt that be 1? The events are independent.

Comment: Are those events intersecting?

Comment: What is the relationship between these events?  Does any one's outcome affect the others?

Comment: the events are independent!

Answer (score 3):

My assumption would be that the question is simply asking for the probability that *at least one* of the events D, F or G happens. Assuming independence, the probability that none of the events happens is given by $\frac{4}{5} \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{7}{8} = \frac{7}{12}$. So the probability that *at least one* of the events happens would be $1 - \frac{7}{12} = \frac{5}{12}$. ${}{}$

Comment: Given my clearly stated interpretation of the question, what's not correct about my answer?

Comment: I read your answer too superficially. Indeed you're correct. If you'd edit your answer a little bit I could vote it up again (otherwise the system tells me my vote is locked...)

Answer (score 2):

If the events are independent, then the probability of the intersections is the product of the individual probabilities.  In that case, let $D_o$ be the event of $D$ exclusively.  We want

$$P(D_o) + P(F_o) + P(G_o)$$

This can easily be read from a Venn diagram:

$$P(D_o) + P(F_o) + P(G_o) = P(D)+P(F)+P(G) - 2 [P(D \cap F) + P(D \cap G) + P(F \cap G)] \\ + 3 P(D \cap F \cap G)$$

Assuming independence, the result is

$$\frac{59}{120} - 2 \left ( \frac{1}{30} + \frac{1}{40} + \frac{1}{48}\right ) + 3 \frac{1}{240} = \frac{83}{240}$$

Comment: As I understood, the question didn't say "one and only one of events should happen".

Comment: Gev,I am in love with you,despite of your awkward name.

Comment: "...one of these events should happen (it doesn't specify which)."  I interpret that language to indicate one of the events and only one, which is what my answer reflects.